# Error G_Calloc v.to.rast

Tags: grass-gis

Using the grass GUI I get this error message:

ERROR: G_calloc: unable to allocate 2004389888 * 8 bytes of memory at raster.c:71

What can i do to remedy this?

Comment: This is a request for about 14.9 GB of memory. Maybe you ran out of memory?

Comment: Tell us which operating system and which GRASS GIS version...

Comment: using Grass 6.4.3 (standard installation with Qgis Vlamiera) for Windows

Comment: I have opened a ticket for this: http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2404

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the memory footprint of v.to.rast with large maps, set in v.to.rast the parameter:

rows=value

to a value much less than the default 4096.

Comment: Good news: the management of the memory has been improved in v.to.rast, now the amount of memory rather than rows can be specified.